# Showing command on toolbar based on perspective

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I want to show a command on the toolbar based on the perspective. I have used core expressions to achieve this as below.

```
   <extension point="org.eclipse.core.expressions.definitions">
      <definition id="onValidationPerspective">
         <with variable="activeWorkbenchWindow.activePerspective">
               <equals value="com.sample.perspective1"/>
          </with>
      </definition>
   </extension>
```

and I have used this in the command tag as below.

```
   <command
        commandId="com.sample.run.root"
        icon="icons/run_exc.gif"
        label="Reset Card"
        style="pulldown">
      <visibleWhen checkEnabled="false">
        <reference
             definitionId="onValidationPerspective">
        </reference>
      </visibleWhen>
   </command>
```

The above code is working fine.

But I want to extend this for mutiple perspectives, i.e. I want to show the commands on the toolbar in 2 perspectives namely `com.sample.perspective1` and `com.sample.perspective2`.

How can I achieve this using core expressions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the OR operation element:

```
<definition id="onValidationPerspective">
    <or>
        <with ...
        <with ...
    </or>
</definition>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<definition id="onValidationPerspective">
    <with variable="activeWorkbenchWindow.activePerspective">
        <or>
            <equals value="com.sample.perspective1"/>
            <equals value="com.sample.perspective2"/>
        </or>
    </with>
</definition>
```