# How can i add a command to a specific perspective

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am trying to add a command to a toolbar(as a contribution) in an eclipse RCP application that has a lot of perspectives, and i want that command to be seen only in a certain perspective(and remain hidden for other perspectives while i switch through them).

---

I have tried using **visibleWhen** but no luck.

```
<command
        commandId="com.example.command.id"
        icon="icons/myIcon.gif"
        label="Test Command" >
      <visibleWhen checkEnabled="false">
        <with variable="activeWorkbenchWindow.activePerspective">
               <equals value="com.example.myPerspective"/>  //the id of the perspective in which my command should be seen
          </with>
      </visibleWhen>
</command>
```

When i tried using this, my command would only show after switching from **com.example.myPerspective** to another perspective.(maybe it gets the perspective i am switching from as active).

---

Another thing that i would like to specify is that i would not like to do this programatically(unless it's something fast). It would not be very productive to do the same thing all over again for every command that needs to behave like this.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: I think this is already answered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10191373/showing-command-on-toolbar-based-on-perspective-in-eclipse

Comment: I already tried that. I even wrote the example. It doesn`t work as it should.

Comment: If the or statement is not working, can you just create a different menu option for different views?

Comment: I need it to be visible for a whole perspective, in the main toolbar. It`s not related at all to the views.